# 100% width absolutely positioned flexbox not constrained by CSS Grid in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox, css-grid

I have some flex elements within a CSS grid and I need to absolutely position one of the elements. I have set the width to 100% so that it takes up the entire column. On Firefox/Chrome/Safari it is working as expected(the element takes up 100% of the 40% width column), however, in IE, the element is not constrained by the 40% column and ends up taking up 100% of the grid. I have `position:relative;` set on the grid container, which I figured would restrict the width of the content within the column, but for some reason on IE it does not.

**Here's what it looks like in IE:**

[image]

**And here's the desired result(and how it looks in modern browsers):**

[image]

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

```css
.container {
  display:-ms-grid;
  display:grid;
  -ms-grid-columns:40% 60%;
      grid-template-columns:40% 60%;
  position:relative;
}

.ele {
  display:-ms-flex;
  display:flex;
}
  .ele:first-child {
    -ms-grid-column-span:1;
    -ms-grid-column:1;
        grid-column:1 / span 1;
    -ms-grid-row-span:1;
    -ms-grid-row:1;
        grid-row:1;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
  }
  .ele:nth-child(2) {
    -ms-grid-column-span:1;
    -ms-grid-column:2;
        grid-column:2 / span 1;
    -ms-grid-row-span:1;
    -ms-grid-row:1;
        grid-row:1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ele">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris aliquam eros quis rhoncus venenatis. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In nec dui interdum, tincidunt metus sed, faucibus est. Aliquam hendrerit arcu in libero pellentesque euismod. Ut eleifend tortor at auctor pellentesque. Curabitur sit amet tincidunt neque. Aliquam ultricies, dolor lobortis euismod pellentesque, lorem arcu egestas lorem, nec consequat sem risus eu risus. Ut eu ex volutpat, semper est id, elementum massa. Praesent metus nibh, pharetra et condimentum vitae, aliquam et massa. Ut vitae efficitur magna. Quisque risus massa, finibus a viverra et, accumsan eget velit. In egestas vestibulum suscipit. Sed vitae iaculis ligula. Suspendisse massa nisl, rutrum a accumsan sit amet, molestie eget sapien. Suspendisse sed nisl quis ligula porta sodales sit amet eget nunc. Mauris luctus lorem tellus, eu egestas diam porttitor nec. 
  </div>
  <div class="ele">
    Some more content goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [grid spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#static-position):

> An absolutely-positioned child of a grid container is out-of-flow and not a grid item, and so does not affect the placement of other items or the sizing of the grid.

Therefore, grid properties on `.ele:first-child`, which is an absolutely-positioned child of a grid container, should be ignored. That's why the element is not constrained by `grid-column` in IE.

Of course, spec guidelines are just that: guidelines. So rendering may vary between browsers. I suspect that's why you're seeing the difference between Chrome, Safari and Firefox and IE.

Comment: IE is reported on caniuse as having a large number of bugs with grid and only supporting an older version of the specification which I don't consider "guidelines" since it is a standard the browser vendors themselves write.

Comment: @Rob, technically, W3C specs may not be called "guidelines". But in reality, they are. Nobody is obligated to adhere to anything in the spec; browsers can implement rendering behaviors however they want. In fact, all browsers deviate from the specs in one way or another, and there is no punishment for such behavior (which would be a consequence of "rules"). For an example of such deviations, read about [interventions](https://github.com/WICG/interventions).

Comment: Think about it this way, if all browsers were required to adhere to spec language, there would be no need for developers to test their code on each browser. (I just saddened myself thinking how much time I could be putting to better use.)

Comment: Not adhering to a standard is true for anything made. Any manufacturer can deviate from published standards, and they do, but risk the expense of incompatibility. While the W3C publishes their work as a "recommendation", the category is titled "standard". WHATWG titles theirs as a "standard". Perhaps de facto standard should be the term but, nevertheless, it is the browser vendors themselves who write these things and I can't think of any better document to listen to than that.

Comment: I'm in complete agreement with what you just wrote. But we were talking about my use of the word "guidelines", which was the subject of your first comment, and the subject of my first response. Your last comment is, in my view, about something else. @Rob

Answer (score 0):

I only need to target IE10+ so what I ended up doing was adding a media query to target only IE 10/11 and set the `width` to 40%:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), screen and (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  
    @media (min-width:768px) {
        .ele:first-child {
            width:40%;
        }
    }
}
```

Now it is working correctly across all browsers.